# Unwanted whitespace after last <li> tag

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've got this really annoying space after the li tags of my unordered list - see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JdfxU/2/)

I've tried all the usual fixes, like floating the anchor tag but no luck. I would expect the three li elements to take up the entire width of the list, but for some reason I'm getting a bit of extra space after the last one.

I'm using percentage widths to size the list items, in case that matters

Seeing this in Chrome and FF on Lubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is     `width: 32%;`

try `li:last-child{    margin-right: 0; float:right}`

Comment: I also think that it's the percentage widths that are causing the problems.  Is there any way you can use fixed widths instead? Floating the `last-child` right will remove the space on the right, but will create uneven spacing between the other `li`'s.  http://jsfiddle.net/ryancowles/wHVXp/

Answer (score 1):

The percentage widths are causing the problem. If you make your browser smaller (or wider), you'll see that the extra space shrinks and even disappears completely.